# Prove that $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n} B_{i}=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

It is given that $\{{A_n\}}$ is a monotone nondecreasing sequence of sets while $\{{B_n\}}$ is defined as: $B_1=A_1,B_2=A_2-A_1$ or in general: $B_n=A_n-A_{n-1}$. Prove that $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n} B_{i}=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}$ for any $n\in\{2,3,\dots\}$ by mathematical induction.

I was already able to prove that $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{2} B_{i}=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{2} A_{i}$ by using the definitions & properties of sets. For step 2, I have $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k} B_{i}=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k} A_{i}$ where $B_k=A_k-A_{k-1}$.
For step 3, show $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k+1} B_{i}=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k+1} A_{i}$ that is,$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k+1} B_{i}= A_{k+1}$.

$$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k+1} B_{i}=(A_{k+1}-A_k)$$
I get lost with how to show that this is equal to $A_{k+1}$.
$$(A_{k+1}-A_k)=A_{k+1}~\cap~A_k^c$$
Would it be right to assume that $A_k^c=\Omega$? Please let me know if I've missed something.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the sequence is monotone non-decreasing tells us immediately that for every $n$:$$\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i=A_n$$

So it is enough to prove that for every $n$: $$\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}B_i=A_n$$

Induction step:$$\bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1}B_i=(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}B_i)\cup B_{n+1}=A_n\cup (A_{n+1}-A_n)=A_{n+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $B_1 \cup \dotsb \cup B_k = A_1 \cup \dotsb \cup A_k$.
Then,
$B_1 \cup \dotsb \cup B_{k+1}$
$=(A_1 \cup \dotsb \cup A_k) \cup (A_{k+1} \cap A_k^c)$
$=(A_1 \cup \dotsb \cup A_{k+1}) \cap (A_1 \cup \dotsb \cup A_k \cup A_k^c)$
$=A_1 \cup \dotsb \cup A_{k+1}$.
Your turn to explain the reasons of every step :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\bigcup_{i=1}^{k+1}B_i=(\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}B_i)\cup B_{k+1}=(\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}A_i ) \cup B_{k+1}$$ by inductive hypothesis.

As the $\{ A_i \}_i $ are non decreasing this reduces to just $A_k \cup B_{k+1}=A_k \cup \ (A_{k+1} - A_k ).$